# pathlib prints the current directory path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

```py
import os
import sys
import pathlib
for folderName,subfolders,filenames in os.walk('/'):
    for filename in filenames:
    #   print(filename)
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            path=pathlib.Path(filename).parent.absolute()
            print("the file "+str(filename)+" has path "+str(path))
```

- I want this script to look for all the pdf files in the os and i also want to print the path of the file but when i run the script it print the file names but prints the path in which i have the python script and not print the path to the pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import os
import sys
import pathlib
    for folderName,subfolders,filenames in os.walk('/'):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
                print(f"the file {filename} has path {folderName}")
```

You don't need pathlib for this one.
pathlib.Path(filename) will consider filename as a relative path, and thus its parent will be the folder from which the script was runned.